# error when connecting oracle in python using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I was trying to connect oracle database using python like below.

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('user/password@host:port/database')
```

I've faced an error when connecting oracle.
DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help.

I've been struggling to figure it out. I used my user name, password, host, port and database('orcl') for example,

`'admin/admin@10.10.10.10:1010/orcl'`.

Why coudn't it connect?

Ahh, btw I'm running all the code in azure notebooks.

Comment: Mismatch in versions of your oracle client and Python install same version as python like x86 or x64

Comment: following link instruction on link https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux followed by pc restart worked for me

Comment: The quickest solution as of 2022 is to use the most recent cx_Oracle release, which is now called python-oracledb.  This doesn't need Oracle Client libraries so you won't see DPI-1047 in the default mode.  See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that you are missing a 64-bit Oracle client installation or it hasn't been configured correctly. Take a look at the link mentioned in the error message. It will give instructions on how to perform the Oracle client installation and configuration.

[Update on behalf of Anthony: his latest cx_Oracle release doesn't need Oracle Client libraries so you won't see the DPI-1047 error if you upgrade.  The driver got renamed to python-oracledb but the API still supports the Python DB API 2.0 specification. See the [homepage](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/).]

Comment: I've figured it out by following all instructions from the link in the error message. I've stepped forward but still got another error haha. Anyway, Thank you but I'm still confused how I install cx_Oracle or something else in azure notebooks. Actually, I did in my local environment...

Comment: So what error are you getting now? Can you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a problem with version 6.X.This problem didnot appeared in 5.X.But for my case a little workaround worked.I installed in my physical machine and only thing that i need to do was a pc reboot or reopen the terminal as i have added in the path of environment variables.You can try to install in physical machine instead using azure notebooks.

Comment: Its actually a problem with installation/configuration. In cx_Oracle 5.x you would have gotten a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error come when your Oracle Client is not installed or LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set where libclntsh.so is present.

if you have Oracle client installed then search for libclntsh.so and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH  as

"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/bds/parcels/ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT/instantclient_11_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Comment: Check following  link for more details for Oracle client installation:

https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full program to connect Oracle using python.
First, you need to install cx_Oracle. to install it fire the below command.

`pip install cx_Oracle`

```js
import cx_Oracle

def get_databse_coonection():
    try:
        host='hostName'
        port ='portnumber'
        serviceName='sid of you database'
        user = 'userName'
        password = 'password'
        dns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host,port,service_name=serviceName)
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, dns)
        cursor = con.cursor()   
        query ="select * from table"
        cursor.execute(query)
        for c in cursor:
            print(c)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e: 
        print("There is a problem with Oracle", e) 
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if con:
            con.close()

get_databse_coonection()
```