# How to install Oracle Client library on cPanel

Tags: python, django, oracle, cpanel

I create Python App throw cPanel and setting database to connect with Oracle DB on AWS. This app run on localhost perfectly. But on host, it missing Oracle Client library with error:

```
Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
```

How to install Oracle Client library on this case. I am a newbie used cPanel. I want fix it on cPanel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error when connecting oracle in python using cx\_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689456/error-when-connecting-oracle-in-python-using-cx-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can install the Oracle Client using cPanel.

I recommend you SSH to the server where your application is installed, then install the Oracle Client.

Don't forget to setup your environment variables 'ORACLE_HOME' and 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.

Helpful Links:

[Linux](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-oracle-client)

[Windows](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#id2)

[Mac](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-oracle-instant-client)

Comment: Thank for helping.